# Replace links to images with img elements w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I'm trying to replace all links to images (.jpg, .png, .tiff, .gif) within a certain div with **img** elements to show the image instead of linking to it.

Eg. it would change

```
<a href="http://domain.com/image.jpg">Any Text Here</a>
```

to

```
<img src="http://domain.com/image.jpg"/>
```

Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a.img').each(function(){
    //assuming they have the image class
    var img = $('<img>',{src: this.href});
    $(this).replaceWith(img);
});
```

try that ^_^

**UPDATE**

if all images dont have the same class:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var ext = getfileextension(this.href);
    switch(ext){
        case '.gif':
        case '.png':
        case '.jpg':
            var img = $('<img>',{src: this.href});
            $(this).replaceWith(img);
            break;
    }

});
function getfileextension(filename) 
{ 
    var dot = filename.lastIndexOf("."); 
    if( dot == -1 ) return ""; 
    var extension = filename.substr(dot,filename.length); 
    return extension; 
}
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/3pXEm/

Comment: They don't have any class. The code would need to only select links with an href ending in .png, .jpg, .tiff or .gif

Comment: I had to make it difficult :)

Comment: noo problem, you can extend that switch case as many extensions as you want ^_^

Comment: @Jordan @Neal see my answer below: you can greatly simplify this with some Ends-With selectors

Answer (score 2):

A simpler version of [Neal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546873/replace-links-to-images-with-img-elements-w-jquery/5546891#5546891), using [Attribute Ends With selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$("a[href$='.png'], a[href$='.jpg'], a[href$='.tiff'], a[href$='.gif']").each(function() {
    var img = $('<img>',{src: this.href});
    $(this).replaceWith(img);
});
```